# How to perform repeated measures ordinal logistic regression using SPSS?

Tags: regression, spss, ordinal-data, logistic

I'm usually a UseR.
However, for didactic purposes I have to use SPSS today.

I have to specify a General linear model with ordinal structure because what I'm examining is:

Change in Likert scale scores (1,2,3,4,5) WITHIN people, BETWEEN intervention groups over 2 timepoints.

I can specify a full factorial model

```
* Generalized Linear Models. 
 GENLIN Question1 (ORDER=ASCENDING) BY Group PrePost Participant (ORDER=ASCENDING) 
  /MODEL Group PrePost Group*PrePost 
  DISTRIBUTION=MULTINOMIAL LINK=CUMLOGIT 
   /CRITERIA METHOD=FISHER(1) SCALE=1 COVB=MODEL MAXITERATIONS=100 MAXSTEPHALVING=5     
   PCONVERGE=1E-006(ABSOLUTE) SINGULAR=1E-012 ANALYSISTYPE=3(LR)      CILEVEL=95 CITYPE=WALD LIKELIHOOD=FULL 
   /MISSING CLASSMISSING=EXCLUDE 
   /PRINT CPS DESCRIPTIVES MODELINFO FIT SUMMARY SOLUTION.
```

But that model doesn't take account of the non-independence of the participant's measures over time.

I'd be massively grateful if someone could help me (help someone else) speify a model that would have a random effects component, taking into account the "clustering within patients".

Comment: If you're used to R and can express it in R it might be useful if you posted that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For repeated measures design use Generalized Estimating Equations menu. This is the same GENLIN command, only REPEATED subcommand will appear wherein you will specify your subject variable (Participant, I assume) and within-subject variable (PrePost, I assume).

Comment: Thanks very much for that - had been fiddling with other "TABS" trying to get it to work. The interaction terms are spat out perfectly. I can go back to R knowing I have done my best for the unfortunate SPSS user.